# How would I programmatically verify gift cards on a website?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm trying to include a feature on my website that verifies retail gift card balances on cards previously registered at the retailer's website by the card holder. Can this simply be done by writing an algorithm that pulls and aggregates this data on my site?

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this by querying a database to verify if a particular gift card has value on it or not. Each time a gift card is issued, it gets scanned and then has value added to it. In a database, you'd create a new row with the card number and card balance. Then when you want to verify value, you'd query the balance of a given card.

**Be warned, this method may not be secure.**

A database table like so:

<kbd>Gift_Card_ID</kbd> <kbd>Gift_Card_Balance</kbd>

<kbd>123456789</kbd>       <kbd>30.00</kbd>

Now some SQL:

```
SELECT Gift_Card_Balance FROM Gift_Cards
WHERE Gift_Card_ID = '123456789'
```

Be aware that this is just an example to illustrate the concept and in no way implies working code to be used an production environment.

You'd need more than just SQL to integrate this into a web environment but that's the basic idea in terms of operation.